# Excel add hyperlink to another table in excel

Tags: excel, hyperlink

I am trying to add a hyperlink from one sheet to a named table on another sheet. I know that if I name the range then I can use the hyperlink, but ideally, I would like to keep it as just a table.

I have a table on `SHEET 2` named `MySpa` - I would like to have a link from `SHEET 1` to that table.

I tried this - `=HYPERLINK(MySpa, "Link to MySpa Table")` but when I click on the link in the cell it doesn't seem to do anything. How can I link from one sheet to a table on another sheet?

Comment: Does [this thread](http://superuser.com/q/403552/529100) help?

Comment: @BruceWayne Unfortunately no. It just adds a reference to that cell. It's the equivalent of using `=A1`

Answer (score 2):

If the table is named and is in the same sheet, prepend a hash (#) and wrap in double quotes as shown below:

```
=HYPERLINK("#TableName", "Click to view")
```

If the table is in another sheet, prepend the sheet name as shown:

```
=HYPERLINK("#SheetName!TableName", "Click to view")
```

The trick is in wrapping the reference in double quotation marks and including the hash sign.

Comment: I tried this and did not find it was necessary to prepend the sheet name when it is in a different sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the cell you wish to have the link, hyperlink, place in this document. If you have named the table you should see it there. If not, make it a named range.

Comment: I know that... but why isn't the table showing up to allow a reference?

Answer (score 0):

(Tables don't show up (at least in Excel 2010), but it's still possible...)

1. You can **create a named reference pointing to the (named) table**, e.g. name it `LnkMyTab` and let it point to `=MyTab`. Now `LnkMyTab` should appear in the hyperlink dialog under *Current Document* and it will be automatically updated as the table may change :)

---

2. Another kind of **workaround** (at least in Excel 2010) **based on static nature of hyperlink formulas** is this:

   (glossary: T: my table,  A: some (temporary) anchor,  L: my hyperlink)

   1. rename your tab `MyTab` to `MyTab_` (T)
   2. create some temporary named reference `MyTab` to some arbitrary range or cell, e.g. `=B10` (A)
   3. create your hyperlink using `MyTab` (L)
   4. delete the temporary `MyTab` (A)

      - (the hyperlink's formula will not be updated and would bring an error if clicked now. this is the "feature" we are using here :))
   5. rename your tab `MyTab_` back to `MyTab` (T)
   6. voilá - the hyperlink should work now

Answer (score 0):

Excel does not recognize a full table in hyperlink, howver there is a simple workaround provided you want to show a single cell from a table, you can use it's cell address to point as a hyperlink.

Suppose your table is named MyTable

**=HYPERLINK(CELL("address",INDIRECT("MyTable"),"Click")**

It will show the first row and column intersection in the table, and it will not be static if you cut paste the table to anywhere it will not get affected since it is based on table object name.

If you are having a call from a different table with same number or rows and want to call the corresponding cell of another table then just add [@ColumnName](the column name you have) inside INDIRECT() along with table name like

**=HYPERLINK(CELL("address",INDIRECT("MyTable[@ColumnName]"),"Click")**

Now it will reference to the same row number as is called from the requesting sheet.